# Using the find function to determine if a value is found in a list with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from a page and trying to determine if a value is in a list using `find` with Beautiful Soup. So, if '4:30' is found on the page, do something else in this case:

```
myList = ['4:28', '4:29', '4:30']
if str(soup).find(myList) == -1:
    # continue with the script,
    continue
else
    # do something else
```

I've also tried:

```
if str(soup).find('4:28') == -1 or str(soup).find('4:29') == -1 or str(soup).find('4:30') == -1:
    # continue with the script,
    continue
else
    # do something else
```

Neither seems to work but I'd prefer a list as I may need to find against 30-60 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the most performant solution but if your string is not that large:

```
myList = ['4:28', '4:29', '4:30']
string1 = "34:28, 4:29, 4:30"
string2 = "other test 5:3"

if any(pattern in string1 for pattern in myList):
    print("found pattern in string 1")
else:
    print("found no pattern in string 1")

if any(pattern in string2 for pattern in myList):
    print("found pattern in string 2")
else:
    print("found no pattern in string 2")
```

However, this question is not really linked to BeautifulSoup but simply to string matching in python.

Comment: I've updated my question because I'm not sure I was very clear. I'm not trying to find a pattern, but trying to determine if one of the values in the list exists on a page. Thanks.

Comment: @Shane That's what this does. The patterns are just fixed strings.

Comment: @Shane just replace `string1` in my example with `str(soup)` and you will get what you are looking for.